# How to organize printing text/output

Tags: java, text

What is good programming practice regarding printing text/output? Should I make a separate class with methods specialzed only for printing? Until now I was simply throwing in a `System.out.print` everywhere needed, but I was thinking about doing this. Is it a good way or a bad way? Or is there a general best way?

I mean, should my code be like this

```
for (int i = P.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(P[i]);
    }
```

or like this

```
for (int i = P.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        object.Print_for();
    }
```

Where object is a separate class specialized `only for print methods`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a class for such uses which are custom to your need and requirement.

It becomes a good practice because in case in the future you wish to change the implementation to a logging to file format or to a stream it will be easier to do..

the core methods implemented by java APIs are good but u would need to make changes in lot of places in case of future changes.

to avoid maintenance hell, implement your wrapper class

Answer (score 0):

Please use Log4J framework for logging stuff irrespective of your coding style.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple special libraries e.g. 
[log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/index.html) and [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)

They provide much more powerful way to log all your program actions. Logging to console, files organizing multiple levels (debug, info, error) etc.